# Rails create a form in haml file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am sorry if this is a bad question, however I am new to HAML.
I have a file movies/show.html.haml and I have to create a form for Comment for a movie in it.

In a typical html.erb file I would this:

```
<%= form_for([@movie, @movie.comments.new]) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :text, class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
<% end %>
```

How can I accomplish this in .haml file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
= form_for([@movie, @movie.comments.new]) do |f|
  = f.text_area :text, class: "form-control"
  = f.submit, class: "btn btn-primary"
```

your file name should `my_file.haml`

there are many tools to convert erb to haml or vice versa you can google it 
here is [one](https://awsm-tools.com/code/html2haml)

Comment: Thank you. I had to add brackets to the last line `= f.submit(class: "btn btn-primary")`

Comment: @jedi yep you forgot to add `%>` at submit button. feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Comment: where can I find documentation on how to create forms in HAML?

Comment: @jedi you can google it , or just convert erb code in to haml using tools. there are many online sites for it.